# ng-change is not working in ui-select2

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2

When I change selection in dropdown ng-change is not fired
Following are my html and js code

```
                            <ui-select ng-model="DemandLine.SupplierId" theme="select2" ng-change="GetSupplierInfo()">
                                <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Select or search supplier in the list...">{{$select.selected.SupplierName}}</ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="supplier.Id as supplier in (Suppliers | filter: $select.search)">
                                    <span ng-bind-html="supplier.SupplierName | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>


$scope.GetSupplierInfo = function () {
    var _supplier = _.find($scope.Suppliers, function (data) { return (data.Id == $scope.DemandLine.SupplierId) });
    if (_supplier != undefined && _supplier != null && _supplier.Active == true) {
        $scope.DemandLine.SupplierId = _supplier.Id;
        $scope.DemandLine.Supplier = _supplier.SupplierName;
    }
    else {
        $scope.DemandLine.SupplierId = null;
        $scope.DemandLine.Supplier = null;
    }
    $scope.setStatus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use  **`on-select`** instead of **`ng-change`** which is an angular directive

```
<ui-select ng-model="DemandLine.SupplierId" theme="select2" on-select="GetSupplierInfo()">
```